# db.[collection_name].watch() giving operation failure

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I was trying to use mongo db event streams for my new project to get the feed of changes happening on specific collection.
After issuing db.[collection_name].watch()command i got below error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The featureCompatibilityVersion must be 3.6 to use the $changeStream stage. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-feature-compatibility.
```

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/

Comment: The error is really verbose. Are you using 3.6 and up? Did you migrate from a lesser version? If so, did you do the migration as directed in the migration plan?

Comment: I am using version 3.6. I didn't set "featureCompatibilityVersion" to 3.6 while updating mongodb version to 3.6 from 3.4.

i got this resolved by setting featureCompatibilityVersion version to 3.6 using below command:

db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )